# Is there a timeline for Girls' Last Tour?

Tags: girls-last-tour

Girls' Last Tour leaves a lot of breadcrumbs to suggest that a technologically advanced future civilization was destroyed, rebuilt at lower level hundreds of years prior to the events of the series, and then destroyed again.

Is there an official timeline for this?